# Burning MKV to VCD

Tags: burning, mkv, vcd

I am trying to use Brasero, to burn a mkv file of 300mb size to a blank CD
and it nags that cd has not enough disk, I used mkvmerge to break it to 4 100 mb files it 
still nags that it cant burn it due to size, anyone knows how may I do it?

Comment: how long is the film?

Comment: 1 hour and half, but I broke it to 4, 20 min-ish pieces it nags the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using devede it may work better than Brasero as its main purpose is to create dvd's and vcd also I would run Brasero from terminal and see what messages are output to terminal.

Finally the max length of a VCD is going to be 80min if you convert the mkv to a "playable" vcd if you are just writing the mkv to the disk as a "data" disk then there should be no problem.

Comment: nothing worked finaly and I gave up but your answer has usefull data so I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

ImgBurn of Windows works in Wine. Use the last version of the program